# error after install android support library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm new in Xamarin and I'm currently facing many error when I try to build a crossplatform project on Xamarin Studio 6.1.2 for windows 8.1 with .NetFramework 4.6.

1.When I tried to build my project for the first time  I got this error message : "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA0000: Could not determine $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for API level '25.' (XA0000) (hieuht3.Droid)"  so I resolved it by get into myprojectName.Droid.scproj file and changed AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk from "true" to "false".

2.Then I built the project again and got this error "Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml(0,0): Error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'".

3.Now I add a nuget pakage to the project called: "amarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.1.1" and this message appear: "Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework"  so I decided to downgrade version of "amarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.1.1" to version 19.x.x and now the pakage is installed to the project successfully.

4.Again I cleaned an rebuilt my project so now I have this error message: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error XA5206: Please install package: 'Android Support Library' available in SDK installer. Android resource directory support/v7/appcompat doesn't exist. (XA5206) (hieuht3.Droid)" .

5. I'm getting stuck in step 4, have found many solution in stackoverflow as well as many other sites but they all seem to be related to these path: "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4" or "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.appcompat" or "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips" but I found there are only 3 folder in side Xamarin folder: "Mono for Android" , "Cache" and "Config".

Someone please help me to resolve this error so I can build my project...!

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of your android sdk manager, Make sure you have latest updated sdks, have installed sdk you are wishing to target

Comment: http://imgur.com/FslTbrz

Comment: Above comment is my SDK Manager screen.